# DNS TXT Record query using non-default DNS server

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, dns

I have my own `DNS server` ex: IP 34.34.34.34.

This server knows about few domain names.

At times I need to send a `TXT` Record query to this server and process the result.

What is the best framework to use for this on iOS?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Nope, I ended up writing my own

Comment: Would one of you guys be so nice and post your solution? I need to do the same and I'm really struggling with this :(

Comment: I need to send a TXT query to the server and process the result. For Mac osx app.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple to do it in C and call it from ObjectiveC.

Here's an example I to get you started: https://gist.github.com/wil/6141275

Just make sure you link with `-lresolv` (i.e. `libresolv.dylib`)